# What is the best between root nodes and namespaces nodes in realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a question about realtime database modeling

I have a lot of data concerning "users" and would like to use :

1.nodes as namespaces like :

```
    /users/accounts/{ids}
    /users/profiles/{ids}
    /users/records/{ids}
```

2. root nodes like :

```
    /usersaccounts/{ids}
    /usersprofiles/{ids}
    /usersrecords/{ids}
```

For 1, I would like to know if filters works on the reference given in the query, or on all `'/users'` nodes ?

For example, I want to filter on `'/users/accounts'` data only when it necessary and not on all `'/users'` nodes to get filtered `'accounts'` data.

What is the best approach between 1 and 2 ?

What about performance ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no significant difference between the two approaches you outlined. Both seem to model flat lists of a single entity, and whether you do that as a top-level, or one level lower makes no significant difference.

What **does** make a difference is if you'd nest different entity types under a single dynamic node.

```
/users/{ids}/accounts
/users/{ids}/profiles
/users/{ids}/records
```

In this model you can only get, and secure access on an entire user, instead of on their accounts, profiles, and records separately. This is why the Firebase documentation recommends that you [avoid nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [flatten data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures).

Answer (score 2):

If you have this database:

```
users
  accounts
      randomId
           accNum: 1234
      randomId
           accNum: 1234
  profiles
      randomId
           profile: 124
      randomId
           profile :125
```

Use this schema if each node will have a lot of data under it, so if `profile` or `accounts` will have alot of data for each user, then use this. Also if you want to query for data inside `accounts` or inside `profile`, then you should use this schema.

For example:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
ref.child("accounts").orderByChild("accNum").equalTo(1234) //1
ref.child("profiles").orderByChild("profile").equalTo(124) //2
```

1- will filter according to accNum inside accounts

2- will filter according to profile inside profiles

---

Basically both the first and the second schema are close to each other, but if you want to retrieve everything inside the `users` node then use this schema.

Comment: I can do one validation only,  and Frank was the fattest ^^ so I put +1

Comment: nope its a 1 min difference, mine was faster :p but I'm joking I'm glad both answers helped you!